# invalid covariant return type ( parameters also inherited )

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am getting this error
invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual JumpState Jump_peg::init()’
I have done this
Can you suggest something what's wrong?

```
class Puzzle{

    public:
        virtual vector<State> getNext(State) = 0;
        virtual State init() = 0;
        virtual bool solved(State) = 0; 
        virtual void print(State) = 0;   
};

class Jump_peg:public Puzzle{

    private: 
    int size;
    public:
        vector<JumpState> getNext(JumpState);
        JumpState init();
        bool solved(JumpState); 
        void print(JumpState);
        void jump(JumpState,int,int,vector<JumpState>&);
};
```

and in my code
jumpstate inherits from state

class JumpState:public State

Comment: forward declare `JumpState` before `Jump_peg` should fix the issue.

Comment: @billz: Nope. That won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Covariant return types work when you return pointers or references, but not class objects. So

```
virtual State& init();
```

would work. Unfortunately, a bigger problem is that

```
virtual vector<State> getNext(State);
```

and

```
vector<JumpState> getNext(JumpState);
```

are totally unrelated functions. The latter does not override the former. The same is true for all other pairs of functions that accept a `State`. To override, parameter types must be identical.

You actually might be needing this:

```
template <class State> class Puzzle { .. 

class Jump_peg : public Puzzle<JumpState> { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that the intention in the code is that `getNext`, `init`, `solve` and `print` are all overridden in the derived type, but that is not the case for different reasons.

In the case of `init`, since there are no arguments, the compiler interprets that you want to override the function by the same name in the base. C++ allows for co-variant types (the return type of the overrider can be a derived type of the type returned by the function in the base) **provided** that the return type is either a *pointer* or *reference*, but **not** a value.

In the case of `solved` and `print` the functions declared in the derived type do **not** override the function declared with the same name in the base as the set of arguments is not the same. C++ supports covariant return types, but the arguments must be the same for a function to override another.

Even if some variation was allowed for the arguments it would have to be *contra-variance*, not co-variance, since co-variance would narrow the contract of the function in the derived type: the base type would take *any* `State`, but the derived type can only take `JumpState`. The derived type would not be substitutable in place of the base, breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Moreover, different template instantiations are unrelated types, no matter what the relationship of the template arguments is, so in the case of `getNext` the types `vector<State>` and `vector<JumpState>` are not related by inheritance even if `State` and `JumpState` are.